# WebView2 - VB.NET - No ZoomFactor Available

Tags: vb.net

According to Microsoft's page on WebView2...
[WebView2 Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/winforms/0-9-515/microsoft-web-webview2-winforms-webview2)

Zoom is an available method.

I have WebView 2 version 0.9.538 installed using NPM
everything works... I can load a page, use go back and forward buttons etc.

However, in code view of Visual Studio 2019, in the code assistant pop-up there is no zoom factor available. I also checked the property of the WebView2 control and there is no zoom factor in there either.

Does anyone know why zoom is not showing up as a method on my control?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on this MS thread...
[MS WebView2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3836031-aa56-4748-b157-df60fb0a226e/webview2-vbnet-no-zoomfactor-available?forum=vbgeneral)